# Do 'regular professional ten' and 'an amateur first-nine' imply the № of club members?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In [the] 1850s, a baseball club might consist of 40 members. By 1868, it was said that a club would **have their regular professional ten**, **an amateur first-nine**, and their "muffins".

Do **ten** and **first-nine** imply the number of club members?

If that's right, can I say that the club was smaller in 1868?

Comment: They would be the regular line-ups drawn out of a club's members for professional and amateur matches.

Comment: They might have had hundreds of "muffins", or they might only have had a couple. The fact that your second sentence starts with ***but*** strongly implies they had at least 22 muffins (10 + 9 + 22 = 41, being ***more*** than the 40 they might have had a decade earlier). But pragmatically, they probably had far more.

Comment: Sr, there is one typo. It's **By 1868**, not **But in 1868**. Is there any significant change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, whether it's ***but*** or ***by***, the context (and, let's face it, common sense) strongly implies membership *increased* between the 1850s and 1868. But I can't really see much relating to "use of English" here - there's just basic maths and logic.

Comment: The (probably original) _full_ (and slightly different) quote may be found by searching for `"1868, it was said that a club would have their regular professional ten"`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, "ten" and "nine" refer to the size of the team.

This sports terminology is not used very much in modern American English, but it is a common occurrence in British English.  For example, [the second-tier team for an English cricket club](http://www.espncricinfo.com/county-cricket-2016/engine/current/series/1009481.html) is called "the second XI" (where XI is Roman-numeral 11).

Answer (score 0):

The numbers used refer only to the size of those teams: ten in the professional and nine in the amateur (the difference being that a professional team were permitted a spare or substitute player).

The club altogether consists of these teams *along with* the "[muffins](http://www.baseballchronology.com/baseball/History/Early-Baseball-Terminology.asp)". Note in that link, further detail of how some clubs had a 'second nine' by the 1880s, under the glossary entry for 'nines'.

Finally, the phrasing of the original text implies that **this is not one specific club** but a general description of how clubs were sized in those respective years. The implication for the 1850s is that forty members would be near to an upper bound and most would not have nearly that number (commensurate with the history of most sports, where a club was often just one team) while by 1868 clubs were regularly putting out two teams in addition to a noteworthy number of other enthusiasts and lower-ability players.